# Form attributes not displaying on webpage

Tags: django

I am trying to add classes to my forms but the classes are not being applied. I cannot find what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm hoping to set bootstrap classes, so I'd like  ,  if possible.

```
class PersonalInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    dob = models.DateTimeField('Date of birth (mm/dd/yyyy)', null=True, default=now)
    preferred_subjects = models.CharField('Are there subjects you would prefer doing?', max_length=200, default='')
```

```
class PersonalInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    OPTIONS = (
        ("ANI", "Animals"),
        ("ART", "Art"),
        ("COM", "Communication"),
    )
    preferred_subjects = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        attrs={
            'class' : 'not working',
            'id' : 'not working'
        }
    ), choices=OPTIONS)

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalInformation

        fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'dob', 'preferred_subjects']
        widgets = {
            'dob': DatePickerInput(
                options={
                    "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
                    "showClose": False,
                    "showClear": False,
                    "showTodayButton": False,
                }
            ),
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Updating the form field attributes on initiallization.

```
class PersonalInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):

OPTIONS = (
    ("ANI", "Animals"),
    ("ART", "Art"),
    ("COM", "Communication"),
)
preferred_subjects = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=OPTIONS)

class Meta:
    model = PersonalInformation

    fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'dob', 'preferred_subjects']
    widgets = {
        'dob': DatePickerInput(
            options={
                "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
                "showClose": False,
                "showClear": False,
                "showTodayButton": False,
            }
        ),
    }

def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PersonalInformationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['preferred_subjects'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'})
```

EDIT:

```
preferred_subjects = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=OPTIONS)

preferred_subjects.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

class Meta:
    model = PersonalInformation

    fields = ['first_name', 'surname', 'dob', 'preferred_subjects']
    widgets = {
        'dob': DatePickerInput(
            options={
                "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
                "showClose": False,
                "showClear": False,
                "showTodayButton": False,
            }
        ),
    }
```

if this doesnt work, consider using 'SelectMultiple' instead of 'CheckboxSelectMultiple'

```
forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(), choices=OPTIONS)
```

Comment: Thank you. That works if I leave it as a CharField (which it is in model), but not when I make it a MultipleChoiceField :(

Comment: Check out the edits i made. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hey. I appreciate the update. Unfortunately that doesn't work either :( It's really stumped me. Thanks very much though